# Oracle asp.net Connecting

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I am using Grid view control to insert data into oracle database but when i run the page i got following errot
"Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed."

Comment: My Version is 2.0 and i have alredy use the system.data from machine.config but still error is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you  [*“Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed”*](https://web.archive.org/web/20120121010025/http://myviewstate.net/blog/post/2009/05/24/e2809cUnable-to-find-the-requested-Net-Framework-Data-Provider-It-may-not-be-installede2809d.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You may access the oracle database via `System.Data.OleDB` or `System.Data.ODBC` or `System.Data.OracleClient` provider. In case of OracleClient, you have to add reference of `System.Data.OracleClient.Dll` (now it is deprecated) into your project/webapp. You can download [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085703.html) (ODP.NET for Microsoft OracleClient Developers).

Comment: from where i get System.Data.OracleClient.Dll ?

Comment: @AdeelAslam - Open Visual studio project/website + Web Site Menu + Add References

Comment: if say then i can send u my web.config file